# expected primary-expression before ',' token

Tags: c++

EDIT: have solved the problem. It was missing the quotation marks around each letter. Thanks for your help, st2000!

---

I am very new to Arduino and C++ (coding in general!). Have copied an example code, only modifying the notes to make my own tune. But when I click 'verify', I am getting the error above, and I can't for the life of me, work out what is wrong! I've searched and read several forums and FAQs, but am just coming up blank. This is the code I have, where the error is occuring:

```
  int melody[]={
    a,C,D, 
    a,a,C,D,D,C, 
    C,C,D,D,C, 
    C,D,E,F,E,D,C};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the source from where you copied the code? Can you provide the wole code? It is hard to tell what is wrong if we don't see the definition of those variables `a C D E F`.

Comment: High likely those notes (a to g, A to G) are either frequency values or mapped frequency values.

Comment: I think the same but I question that they have been defined anywhere in the code. Thus leading to the compiler error message.

Comment: Guessing, I think the OP has based their project on [this example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/melody).

Comment: So, what is `a,C,D, a,a,C,D,D,C`? What are these identifiers referring to?

Comment: Have you noticed your `#define …` does not define anything? (well it defines letters but with no meaning except that they are defined)

Comment: Close it. It is a question about an error caused by a mere typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question we will assume your project is based on [the Melody example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/melody) at www.arduino.cc.

Likely you wanted to enter the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) values of these letters into an array of [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) char (type int would work as well.  But, in some cases, char would be more efficient).  To do this you need to place single quotes around each letter.  Specifically, you need to change your code:

```
int melody[]={ a,C,D, a,a,C,D,D,C, C,C,D,D,C, C,D,E,F,E,D,C};
```

...so that your line of code look like this:

```
int melody[]={'a','C','D','a','a','C','D','D','C','C','C','D','D','C','C','D','E','F','E','D','C'};
```

Comment: This is an assumption that doesn't seem right to me. Storing `char`-s in an array of `int`-s is a waste of space.

Comment: @Kwasmich, you may be correct.  I think I have see some processor / C compiler combinations which handled 8 bit values as if they were 16 bits.  Wasting memory space in favor of speed.

Comment: @st2000: In C, for example. In C language character constants are `int` value. There's nothing unusual in seeing a C platform with 16-bit `int` to handle character constants as 16-bit values. That's how C language requires them to be handled.

Comment: I have no idea what the above means (yet!), but this solution has worked for me. Thank you :)

Comment: @user60325, What a compiler does "behind the curtain" when optimizing code is sometimes confusing.  And is not necessarily the domain of the beginner programmer.  But, if you want to know more [this Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150447/c-question-why-char-actually-occupies-4-bytes-in-memory) (read the answer which starts w/"Let's look at your output...") can get you started.